# Android - Paypal checkout got stuck in webview thankyou page

Tags: java, android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

`I am integrating the PayPal Checkout SDK (version 0.8.1) into my Android app to process payments. The SDK is initializing correctly, and I'm able to add the email address for payment. However, when I tap on "Complete Purchase," the SDK navigates to a WebView showing the PayPal payment screen. After completing the payment in the WebView, it gets stuck at the message "Thank you for using PayPal" and doesn't return back to my app.

After completing the payment in the PayPal WebView, the SDK doesn't return to my app. Instead, it gets stuck on a page displaying "Thank you for using PayPal."

Expected Behavior:
After the payment is successfully completed in the PayPal WebView, I expect the SDK to return to my app and trigger the approval callback in the registerCallbacks method.

```
PayPalCheckout.setConfig(new CheckoutConfig(this, clientId, Environment.SANDBOX,
    CurrencyCode.EUR,UserAction.PAY_NOW));

PayPalCheckout.registerCallbacks(
    approval -\> { // Order is approved
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // navigateToThankYouPage(payment);
    },
    () -\> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Optional callback for when a buyer cancels the order
    },
    errorInfo -\> { // Optional error callback
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
);

PayPalCheckout.startCheckout(
    createOrderActions -\> {
        ArrayList\<PurchaseUnit\> purchaseUnits = new ArrayList\<\>();
        purchaseUnits.add(
            new PurchaseUnit.Builder().amount(
                new Amount.Builder()
                .currencyCode(CurrencyCode.EUR)
                .value((String)grandTotalTv.getTag())
                .build()
            ).build()
        );
        Order order = new Order(OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
            new AppContext.Builder()
            .userAction(UserAction.PAY_NOW)
            .build(), purchaseUnits);
        createOrderActions.create(order, orderId -\> {});
    }
);
```

After the payment is successfully completed in the PayPal WebView, I expect the SDK to return to my app and trigger the approval callback in the registerCallbacks method.